# Loading a registry entry into a wso2 property mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am currently loading data from a local entry in the wso2 esb using the following satement:

```
<property name="MAPPING" expression="get-property('mapping_id_ep_v1')" />
```

It loads the following local entry with the name mapping_id_ep_v1:

```
<mappings>
    <mapping id="ep_1">http://localhost:8280/services/ep_1</mapping>
    <mapping id="ep_2">http://localhost:8280/services/ep_2</mapping>
    <mapping id="ep_3">http://localhost:8280/services/ep_3</mapping>
<mappings>
```

I would like to load the data from a registry entry. I thought the following would work:

However, it throws an exception:

```
Evaluation of the XPath expression conf:/custom/inspectieview/routing.xml') resulted in an error {org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath}
org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: Cannot resolve namespace prefix 'conf'
```

Anyone know if it is possible to load a value from the registry into a property mediator?

Regards, nidkil

Answer (score 6):

I solved my question. For anyone interested in the solution it is actually very simple. The following code loads a resource stored in the registry into a property that can be referenced in a mediator /sequence / etc.

```
<property name="MAPPING" expression="get-property('gov:/custom/service/resource')" />
```

Regards, nidkil

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve your requirement using the below configuration.

```
 <property name="testProp" expression="get-property('registry', 'gov://custom/testEntry')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this

http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/message_mediation_samples.html

Sample 8 and following will help you

Comment: Hi fipries, thx for your ressponse. The sample you are referencing is about local entries. Working with local entries works fine for me. My question is how to do the same, but with a resource stored in the registry. Regards, nidkil