# WSO2 API Manager - unable to access resource properties

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am not able to access resource property `test1`, mentioned in property section in the screenshot.

I am trying to access it by using the expression. `get-property('test1')`. I am expecting this result in console as `test1-value`. But the is showing as `null`.[image]

**Updated**

I have tried following options but nothing is working for this `test1` property.

```
<property expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/data/xml/collectionx@test1')" name="test_property2"/>
<property expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences/in/Seq1.xml@test1')" name="test_property4"/>
<property expression="get-property('gov:/_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences/in/Seq1.xml@test1')" name="test_property6"/>
```

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210545/loading-a-registry-entry-into-a-wso2-property-mediator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of `test1`, use following property.

```
<property expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/apimgt/customsequences/in/Seq1.xml@test1')" name="test_property5"/>
```

From above example the location of resource is showing `/_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences/in/Seq1.xml`. So to make its path, we will use subpath and leave `/_system/governance` from the beginning. The path will be `gov:/apimgt/customsequences/in/Seq1.xml`. Now to access `test1` property, simply append `@test1` to the path.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<property name="regProperty" expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/data/xml/collectionx@abc')"/>
```

Ref: http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2015/09/wso2-esb-how-to-read-registry-property.html

Comment: please give sample for above example. I am not getting what have to use for above example.

Comment: or please explain how to create `test1` property in `/data/xml/collectionx` collection.